# How to plot elevation charts from a GPX file that has elevation data

Tags: elevation, gpx, chart

Is there a service or package that converts a GPX file into an elevation chart?

I need either a CLI, a Web API, or a library/other software that could be wrapped up as a small service.

The GPX files already have embedded elevation -  I'm *not* looking for a service that returns elevation for a particular lat/lng.

Preferred output would be a PNG or SVG, though a javascript chart would also be good.

Comment: Can you add an example of what you mean by "elevation chart"? Are you just talking about a line graph with elevation on the Y-axis and distance on the X-axis? If that's the case you'll need to define what you mean distance (eg as-the-crow-flies distance from the start point, distance along the line, etc).

Comment: http://www.gpsvisualizer.com/ > upload your gpx and choose elevation profile. for more detailed settings go to http://www.gpsvisualizer.com/profile_input output format is either PNG/JPEG/SVG